# Kafka Auto Rebalance Config

Tags: apache-kafka

I saw the below in Kafka documentation. Please can you let me know which config file I have to lookup this config?

> Since running this command can be tedious you can also configure Kafka
>   to do this automatically by setting the following configuration:
>       auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of the [broker configuration](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs) which is the configuration file passed to `kafka-server-start.sh`. In the distribution the file is called `server.properties`.

Comment: Thanks Martin. auto.leader.rebalance.enable flag is not set in my property file. Does it mean that a leader will not be selected if the primary kafka node for a partition fails?

Comment: No, the default value is true so you don't need to set it